# driver=radeon on ubuntu 22.04 with a Radeon R9 390 graphic card

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, radeon, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and I have an `AMD Radeon R9 390` graphic card and an `AMD® Ryzen 5 3600x 6-core` CPU.
Sometimes my computer simply either freezes or reboots out of nowhere, specially when watching a movie/youtube. When the computer starts again I see in the console an error code `8701013`.

Googling it I get several people complaining about the same issue with the same combination of CPU and graphic card.
From the google results it seems to be an issue with the graphic card driver so I decied to  run `sudo lshw -c video` I get:

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 80
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=3440,1440
   resources: irq:98 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fce00000-fce3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

It says `driver=radeon` while I was expecting to see `driver=amdgpu`.

Googling `driver=radeon` seems to indicate it is a legacy gpu driver.

How can I install and make sure the latest amdgpu driver is properly installed?

Comment: Googling its release date it gives series 300 (up to 390X) as 2015 so yes, legacy therefore supported by `radeon`.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-Driver

The above link informs which AMD chipsets are supported by `amdgpu`.

Everything else older than the aforementioned architectures is supported by `radeon` and that includes the 2015 R9 390.